# How to bulk update the many-to-many field of a Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

How does one update - in bulk - a many to many field in the queryset of a Django data model?

For instance, I have a data model called `Photo`, and another called `PhotoStream`. In `Photo`, I have `which_stream = models.ManyToManyField(PhotoStream)`.

I extracted a queryset of `Photos` called `childhood_photos`, and I need to add a new `PhotoStream` object in the many-to-many fields of all objects within this queryset. Let's call this PhotoStream object `for_classmates`.

I try `childhood_photos.update(which_stream.add(for_classmates))`, but it gives me an error: **global name 'which_stream' is not defined**.

How can I do this operation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access the through model of your m2n relationship via the field's `.through` attribute (see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)). That will allow you to bulk create the necessary through model instances:

```
through_model = Photo.which_stream.through  # gives you access to auto-created through model
# print through_model
# <class 'app_label.models.Photo_which_stream'>  # or sth. similar

through_model.objects.bulk_create([
    through_model(photo_id=pk, photostream_id=for_classmates.pk) 
        for pk in childhood_photos.values_list('pk', flat=True)
])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. By the looks of this, this is **creating** new fields, but solely in the `through` table. To my mind, that's what the **update** procedure I was trying does too. Hence they're equivalent. Wanted to confirm I have it correct in my head, yes?

Comment: What do you mean by 'solely in the through table'? The through table is the ONLY place where anything ever really happens for a `ManyToManyField`! This is not creating new fields (!?), but adds the  for_classmates` stream to all the desired photos.

Comment: Using `update` operation only updates the fields which are on that particular model. The thing about M2M fields are that they are not actually created in the particular table but a new through table is created in the database relating your first and second table. So doing `update` in `Photo` model for updating streams is not same as creating rows in through table.