# sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed | When using bulk adding many-to-many relation

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models, where one of them has a TreeManyToMany field (a many-to-many field for [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) models).

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
   pass

class Product(models.Model):
   categories = TreeManyToManyField('ProductCategory')
```

I'm trying to add categories to the Product objects **in bulk** by using the *through*-table, as seen [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090582/proper-way-to-bulk-create-for-manytomany-field-django) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822493/how-to-bulk-update-the-many-to-many-field-of-a-django-queryset).

I do this with a list of pairs: *product_id* and *productcategory_id*, which is also what my through-table contains. This yields the following error:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: products_product_categories.product_id, products_product_categories.productcategory_id
```

My code looks as follows:

```
def bulk_add_cats(generic_df):

    # A pandas dataframe where ["product_object"] is the product_id 
    # and ["found_categories"] is the productcategory_id to add to that product.
    generic_df = generic_df.explode("found_categories")
    generic_df["product_object"] = generic_df.apply(
        lambda x: Product.objects.filter(
            merchant = x["forhandler"], product_id = x["produktid"]
            ).values('id')[0]['id'], axis=1
    )
    
    # The actual code
    # Here row.product_object is the product_id and row.found_categories is one
    # particular productcategory_id, so they make up a pair to add to the through-table.
    through_objs = [
        Product.categories.through(
            product_id = row.product_object,
            productcategory_id = row.found_categories
        ) for row in generic_df.itertuples()
    ]
    Product.categories.through.objects.bulk_create(through_objs, batch_size=1000)
```

I have also done the following, to check that there are no duplicate pairs in the set of pairs that I want to add. There were none:

```
print(generic_df[generic_df.duplicated(subset=['product_object','found_categories'], keep=False)])
```

I suspect that the error happens because some of the *product-to-productcategory* relations already exist in the table. So maybe I should check if that is the case first, for each of the pairs, and then do the bulk_create. I just want to hope to retain effiency and would be sad if I have to iterate through each pair to check. Is there are way to bulk-update-or-create for this type of problem?

Or what do you think? Any help is highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably check if the reason why you are having those errors is because of duplicate data. If that's the case, I think the `ignore_conflicts` parameter of `bulk_create` can solve your problem. It will save every valid entry and ignore those who have duplicate conflict.

Check the doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create

Comment: I saw that attribute, but I read it as ignore_conflicts would add the relation anyway - meaning duplicates would be present in the database. But I guess not. 

Do you think there is an efficient way to check for duplicates between the exisiting relations table and the external data?

Comment: I guess one way to do so imply db query minimisation.
So If you have a table Product and some unique value or couple of values (let say key1, key2) you can use filter and Q.
Product.objects.filter(Q(key1=v1, key2=v2) | Q(key1=v3, key2=v4) | etc.).exist()